# How to extract the data from a GML file to a shapefile format? or select only few features from a large GML file?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, gml

I have a very big GML file on buildings in Denmark. (I could only download a 'whole country' in one file, so it is big as 17GB, no.of features over 1million). I only need a very few of them in a small local area (40km2 and 20k features). How can I extract this? I am not familiar with GML format. (I tried to do this with select feature> save selected features> to a shapefile (I deselect lots of attribute columns, and kept only 3). But it is keep running for hours, almost 12). How can I make this done? Is there any other way?

QGIS 3.14

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS platform in use, and provide details on network and disk performance constraints.

Comment: I am not sure on network and disk performance constraints. It is showing CPU is being used 35-40% when it is running.

Comment: `ogr2ogr` is usually the best way to do this

Comment: GML is a text format that does not support any kind of indexing. Also because it is XML the document is ready only once the last line is read. Direct access to small area is guaranteed to be slow. The fastest solution if you need to select many small areas  could be to convert all the data with ogr2ogr into for example GeoPackage and then select the area of interest from the GeoPackage by using ogr2ogr with the `-spat`option. If it is just one selection you can use `-spat` right ahead.